# Mono winforms failed to render persian text on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian, mono, winforms

I'm trying to run a Persian application in mono. But the texts are disconnected and reversed.

I'm running this test app on Ubuntu 19.04 (gnome in X11) I also tried running it on a Raspberry pi (Raspbian Buster) and fedora 30 (Gnome X11) but no deference.

I also tried setting LANG environment variable to fa_IR.utf-8 but again no deference.

I also set the RightToLeft property of the form to yes but again no deference.

The app Looks Like [this](https://i.ibb.co/0tjqL5y/tt.png)